# How to solve the error of collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: qt-creator

When I make a use of Qwebview in my application. and then build it I get an error of

```
:: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
:: error: [debug\Browseweb.exe] Error 1
```

so it does not run I have seached Quit But didn't got the solution So what should I do to solve this error. if You have a Solution kindly help me.

Comment: *"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"* is a signature for [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (GCC linker error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is coming from the linker `ld` and, based on `error: [debug\Browseweb.exe] Error 1`, my first thought is that it's a problem creating the executable file.

If that error 1 matches what's in errno.h, then it's an EPERM error which is related to permissions. You should check whether the `debug` directory exists and, if it does, check to make sure you can create files in there.

However, given that you seem to be on a Windows platform (due to the backslash path separator and an exe extension), I'm not sure that's the actual case.

One other thing that may be causing the problem is if your executable is *running* when you try to rebuild it.

I've seen this problem before under Windows since the OS locks the executable while it's running.

Comment: Well, that depends on whether my (educated) guesses are correct. Are you actually running the executable at the time when you try to build it? Can you create files in that debug directory? Does `debug\Browseweb.exe` already exist and can you delete it and try to build again?